# NSIS Installer size increased 50%. Where should I look?

Tags: windows, installation, nsis

My application installer went from 900K to 1.5M after a few code revisions. After I install, the sizes of the installed folders are 3.0M and 3.2M respectively. Not sure what went wrong. Does anyone have an idea of where I should look?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`SetCompress`, `SetCompressor`, `SetCompressorDictSize` and `SetDatablockOptimize` would be my first guess...

Comment: Thanks. This helped a bit but not much. My file size reduced by 1kb.

Comment: Without sample code it is very hard to do anything other than guessing. Maybe you could look at the compiler output/compression ratio or maybe remove files one by one to see where the size increase comes from...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've used a plugin with a big dll file. check your plugin calls (lines that contains `::`). If you are compiling the plugins yourself, you could mistakenly compiled them with debug information which increases the size of the dll's.

Comment: true, I added a dll that was 150K bigger. But that shouldnt cause a 500K size increase with the installer. Do you think the the compression algorithm, LZMA,  could lose its efficiency when the number of files increase?

Comment: On the context menu there's `Compile NSIS Script (choose compressor)` then choose `Best Compressor` - it will compile the installer several times and will find the compressor that works best on your data.